# Using an aggregate for totals using Rollup

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am experimenting with using Rollup, and wanted to find out if there's a way to achieve this without using a subquery, CTE or Temp Table. Here's my code:

```
    select coalesce(Answer,case Grouping_ID(Answer) when 1 then 'Total' end) as Answer
    , Count(*) as CSAT_Count
    , Case Answer
        when 'Average' then 2*count(*)
        when 'Outstanding' then 3*Count(*)
        when 'Unsatisfactory' then 1*Count(*) 
      end as CSAT_Score
from CSAT_Table
Where Empl_ID = 98
Group by Answer
with rollup
```

Here's the result:

```
     Answer               CSAT_Count    CSAT_Score
    ----------------------------------------------
     Average              13            26
     Outstanding          126           378
     Unstatisfactory      6             6
     Total                145           NULL
```

I'd like to have the NULL returning in CSAT_Score reflect the sum of the scores, but I'm thinking because the score is relying on COUNT(*) to be calculated, I can't get Rollup to do this for me, since I can't group by an aggregate.

Like I said above, I know a subquery, CTE or Temp table storing the result of the count would work, but since I'm new to using Rollup, I wanted to see if there was something else I could do with that function to make this work.

Thanks

Comment: Just curious: Why are you so heavily against a solution with a CTE or Temp Table?

Comment: @SQL_M  *since I'm new to using Rollup, I wanted to see if there was something else I could do with that function to make this work.*

Comment: As far as I am aware, you cannot do this using `with rollup`, so the derived table route is your best bet.

Comment: @SQL_M - I'm not against it, just trying to make sure I understand how Rollup works. I know exactly how I'd do this with a CTE/Temp Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of your script working with `rollup`. ( by the way, it produces the same result )

```
  select coalesce(Answer,case Grouping_ID(Answer) when 1 then 'Total' end) as Answer
    , Count(*) as CSAT_Count
    , Sum(Case Answer
        when 'Average' then 2
        when 'Outstanding' then 3
        when 'Unsatisfactory' then 1
      end) as CSAT_Score
from CSAT_Table
Where Empl_ID = 98
Group by Answer
with rollup
```

Comment: That does it!! Thanks!!